# call_user_func_array in Laravel with $this

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have:

```
$this->addRow('$this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual', [$teamMember, $date->year, $date->month], $year, 'Stage target', 'target', $teamMember->image);
```

But it gives me the error:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '$this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual' not found or invalid function name
```

How do I get this to work?

---

```
protected function addRow($func, $params, $data, $year, $traderName, $rowName, $type, $image = null) {
    $date = Carbon::createFromDate($year, 4, 1);
    $total = 0;
    $traderName = $traderName.' '.str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($rowName));
    $params[] = $date->month;
    for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $result = call_user_func_array($func, $params);
        $data['traders'][$traderName]['amounts'][] = $result;
        $total += $result;
        $date->addMonth();
    }
    $data['traders'][$traderName]['amounts'][] = $total;
    $data['traders'][$traderName]['image'] = $image;
    $data['traders'][$traderName]['row_name'] = $rowName;
    $data['traders'][$traderName]['row_type'] = $type;
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: why you pass a variable inside ' ' ? also if dateTargetedActualy is a function you suppose to use () after so I think this one should be 

$this->addRow($this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual(), [$teamMember, $date->year, $date->month], $year, 'Stage target', 'target', $teamMember->image);

Comment: What is the value of `$this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual`? Does it store a function? Or are you wanting your `addRow()` function to call `dateTargetedActual()` on the `$this->userRepo` object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not wrap `$this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual` as string.

Try this:
`$this->addRow($this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual(), [$teamMember, $date->year, $date->month], $year, 'Stage target', 'target', $teamMember->image);`

Comment: What about [$this->userRepo, 'dateStagesTarget'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have the code for `addRow`, we have to guess based on the error messages that the first parameter to `addRow` is being passed as the first parameter to `call_user_func_array()`, which expects the first parameter to be a callback.

If `$this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual` actually holds a callback function, then you just need to pass that value in without quoting it, and it will be executed by the `call_user_func_array()` function.

```
$this->addRow($this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual, [$teamMember, $date->year, $date->month], $year, 'Stage target', 'target', $teamMember->image);
```

If `$this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual` holds a piece of data, and you need a callback function to return that piece of data, then you can define that inline to the function call:

```
$this->addRow(
    function () {
        return $this->userRepo->dateTargetedActual;
    },
    [$teamMember, $date->year, $date->month],
    $year,
    'Stage target',
    'target',
    $teamMember->image
);
```